# Libreoffice 5 problem

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, lts, spell-checking

I have a problem with the Greek language in LibreOffice, it doesn't underline the misspelled words. I have already downloaded applications, dictionary for Greek and English but the problem still remains.

Comment: Have you tried going to `Tools` > `Language` > `For all text` > `Greek`?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis. Yes i' ve tried many times. I read an article that LibreOffice has update into 5.1.I' am waiting for updates.